# Are there limitations on what I can name an element when I am creating a directive in AngulaJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am wanting to create a directive for this code. I would like to pass in the text that's currently `xxxxx` as a parameter inside of the element. Not quite sure how to do this.

```
    <div class="gridFooter" ng-show="home.dataRetrieved">
        <span ng-show="(home.grid.data).length">{{ (home.grid.data).length + " rows retrieved - " +  home.grid.view.length + " displayed" }}</span>
        <span ng-show="!(home.grid.data).length">xxxxx</span>
    </div>
```

I would like it to use `restrict: 'E'`

Can someone tell me if it is valid for me to name the element as `<grid-footer>` also if not then are HTML element names case sensitive? For example could I name the element `<gridFooter>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be here:

#### [Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). **However, since HTML is case-insensitive**, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

We should use naming (in html) like:

```
<grid-footer>
<grid:footer>
```

because HTML is case insensitive - and this is the only way how to instruct angular how to convert that into directive named as **`gridFooter`**

Answer (score 2):

The naming of directives are done in camelCase and when used the name is lowercased and dashes are inserted before the previously uppercased letters.

So if you name your directive `myDirective` the tag would be `<my-directive>`

This should be covered in more detail in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

In HTML, tag names are not case sensitive.